# Consequences to reducing `checkblocks` in console on a node?

Tags: bitcoin-core

At start up it will check the last N number of blocks to verify, default is 288 or 48 hours. If I changed mine to 72, approx the last 12 hours instead are there any foreseeable negative consequences to doing so? Would my node still be considered valid, would it increase my ban score, or disable the wallet feature as it does to those who run pruned nodes, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkblocks` and `checklevel` are simply for local sanity. It's just making sure when your node is coming up that things aren't completely crazy, it won't catch malicious alteration or set any flags anywhere. If the checks fail the node won't start up at all and will show nasty error messages. Turning them down in all probability won't have any impact on you, the only downside is that if your node state is left inconsistent the sanity check might not catch it.